# "Melt" columns into rows

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have SQL Server with some information about users "name, id" and lots of columns that represent items they have: `item_no, item_desc, item_val`.

The problem is instead of multiple rows with one item each our database has lots of columns, one for each item, i.e:

John has 3 items and Jane has only 1:

| Id | Name | item_no1 | item_desc1 | item_val1 | item_no2 | item_desc2 | item_val2.... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 01 | Item XYZ | $52,23 | 02 | Item ABC | $67,24 |
| 2 | Jane | 01 | Item XYZ | $12,34 |  |  |  |

What I have right now:

```sql
SELECT
    id AS "User ID",
    name AS "User Name",
    item_no1,
    item_desc1,
    item_val1,
    item_no2,
    item_desc2,
    item_val2,
    ....
FROM 
    UItems
```

I'm trying to come up with a `SELECT` statement that will turn the multiple columns into 3 unique ones and for each item creates a new row.

I tried using `UNPIVOT()` but had no luck with it, my query kept returning an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value

Expected output:

| Id | Name | item_no | item_desc | item_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 01 | Item XYZ | $52,23 |
| 1 | John | 02 | Item ABC | $67,24 |
| 1 | John | 03 | Item QWE | $32,23 |
| 2 | Jane | 01 | Item XYZ | $12,34 |

I don't now if its important/relevant to say but I have some `CASE` expressions in my current query.

I tried what @Thom A suggested in their answer:

```sql
SELECT 
    pTable.name,
    pTable.id,
    sTable.itemNo,
    sTable.itemDesc,
    sTable.itemVal

FROM Fluig.dbo.ML001281 AS pTable
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES(pTable.itemNo1, pTable.itemDesc1, pTable.itemVal1),
              (pTable.itemNo2, pTable.itemDesc2, pTable.itemVal2),
              (pTable.itemNo3, pTable.itemDesc3, pTable.itemVal3),
              (pTable.itemNo4, pTable.itemDesc4, pTable.itemVal4),
              (pTable.itemNo5, pTable.itemDesc5, pTable.itemVal5),
              (pTable.itemNo6, pTable.itemDesc6, pTable.itemVal6)
    ) sTable(itemNo, itemDesc, itemVal)

WHERE pTable.id = '1';
```

it "works" but its returning empty columns:

| Id | Name | item_no | item_desc | item_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 01 | Item XYZ | $52,23 |
| 1 | John | 02 | Item ABC | $67,24 |
| 1 | John | 03 | Item QWE | $32,23 |
| 1 | Jane |  |  |  |
| 1 | John |  |  |  |
| 1 | John |  |  |  |

I need a way to filter the empty ones.

Last Edit: Pardon, I'm dumb, a simple " where item_no != '' " solves my problem.... :facepalm:

Thanks for the help @Thom_A!!